# Having trouble with bulk_create()-ing models in Django

Tags: django, database, model

1. The first problem is that I have a Question model and a Tags model, which share a ManyToMany relationship and Django doesn't allow direct assignment to them during creation. So the only solution I could find is to create the questions and then manually assign the tags to them, creating hundreds of slow queries.

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
        user_profiles = list(Profile.objects.all())
        if not user_profiles:
            print("No users found to create questions")
            return
        tags = list(Tag.objects.all())
        
        new_questions = [Question(
                        title=random_sentence(12, 12),
                        content=random_text(12, 12, 12),
                        author=random.choice(user_profiles),
                    ) for _ in range(options['questions_num'][0])]
        new_questions = Question.objects.bulk_create(new_questions)

        for question in new_questions:
            question.tags.set([random.choice(tags) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 4))])
```

2. The second problem is about bulk-creating users. I have a Profile model associated with the default Django User model with some additional fields, so I have to create both. But I have to keep in mind the unique constraint of each user and that would mean manually checking if they exist for each of them. Ignoring conflicts during bulk_create means that all the objects won't have primary keys and will be useless to me.

   def handle(self, *args, **options):
   username_length = User._meta.get_field('username').max_length
   password_length = User._meta.get_field('password').max_length
   email_length = User._meta.get_field('email').max_length - len('@mail.ru')

   ```
    try:
        users = [User(
                username=random_word(username_length),
                password=random_word(password_length),
                email=f"{random_word(email_length)}@mail.ru",
            ) for _ in range(options['users_num'][0])]

        #users = User.objects.bulk_create(users, ignore_conflicts=True)
        for user in users:
            user.save()

        print(f"{len(users)} users have been added successfully")
    except IntegrityError as error:
        print(error)
        return

    nickname_length = Profile._meta.get_field('nickname').max_length

    try:
        profiles = [Profile(
                user=user,
                nickname=random_word(nickname_length),
            ) for user in users]

        profiles = Profile.objects.bulk_create(profiles, ignore_conflicts=True)

        print(f"{len(profiles)} user profiles have been added successfully")
    except IntegrityError as error:
        print(error)
        return
   ```

Can someone please help? I've been stuck on this all day.

I was expecting a proper database and what I got was a load of horse bologna.